# Issues after Flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter

I am completely lost.

Last week I was working in a project that was running nice.

Then I began working on another project and upgraded my Flutter version to the last version

```
Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.0)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Today I needed to make some changes in the project from last week, and suddenly I find out that the project has errors on 5 files.

All errors are related to the package geocoder2.

As example here you have where the issue is:

```
 onSelected: (Place place) async {
                    FetchGeocoder fetchGeocoder =
                    await Geocoder2.getCoordinatesFromAddress(
                        address: place.description,
                        googleMapApiKey:
                        "A---");
                    var first = fetchGeocoder.results.first;

                    var lat = first.geometry.location.lat;
                    var lng = first.geometry.location.lng;
                    LatLng sitio = LatLng(lat, lng);
```

The error says `Undefined class 'FetchGeocoder`, which was there before without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the package versions in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev), the package started to rename `FetchGeocoder` to `GeoData` starting from version `1.0.4`, here is a latest from the newest version in pub.dev:

```
GeoData data = await Geocoder2.getDataFromAddress(
    address: "277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    googleMapApiKey: "GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY",
);

//Formated Address
print(data.address);
//City Name
print(data.city);
//Country Name
print(data.country);
//Country Code
print(data.countryCode);
//Latitude
print(data.latitude);
//Longitude
print(data.longitude);
//Postal Code
print(data.postalCode);
//State
print(data.state);
//Street Number
print(data.street_number);
```

**Note:** This problem is a mistake from the package author because for the breaking and major changes the major version number should be changed and the documentation should contain a section for migration.

Because the author just changed the patch number in the version so it becomes `1.0.4` from `1.0.3` instead of being `2.0.0` and properly you are writing the version with `^` sign in `pubspec.yaml`, Flutter pulls the latest version before the new major version of the package automatically, and that's what caused the problem for you without changing anything.